# Update a binary field

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, varbinary

How to update a binary field from 0x54 to 0x46 (T to F)?

```
Update dbo.table1
set field = convert(varchar,field,0x46)
where fieldID = '1'
```

Comment: There was clearly a typo in the code sample (a quotation mark before the `0x46`), which I took the liberty to fix because the main issue here appears to be the wrong usage of CONVERT.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the field is of BINARY datatype:

```
UPDATE [dbo].[Table]
SET [field] = CONVERT(BINARY,'F')
WHERE [fieldID] = 1;
```

Here's my proof of concept:

```
CREATE TABLE #TempBinTable
 ([Identity] INT
,[BinColumn] BINARY);

INSERT INTO #TempBinTable
VALUES(1,CONVERT(BINARY,'T'));

SELECT [Identity], [BinColumn]
FROM #TempBinTable;
--RESULT
----Identity    | BinColumn
----1           | 0X54

UPDATE #TempBinTable
SET [BinColumn] = CONVERT(BINARY,'F')
WHERE [BinColumn] = CONVERT(BINARY,'T');

SELECT [Identity], [BinColumn]
FROM #TempBinTable;
--RESULT
----Identity    | BinColumn
----1           | 0X46

DROP TABLE #TempBinTable;
```

Comment: `UPDATE ... SET [BinColumn] = 0x46
WHERE [BinColumn] = 0x54 ;` should work, too, right?

Comment: Yeah absolutely,  I don't see why not!  The assumption by me back when I answered this was knowledge of hex codes off hand.

Answer (score 1):

Declare a variable with the correct datatype, assign the value, and update with that value.

```
-- Asume VARBINARY(10) is the correct datatype
DECLARE @updateValue VARBINARY(10) = 0x46;

UPDATE dbo.table1
SET field = @updateValue
WHERE fieldID = 1;
GO
```

If you want an inline update, do this:

```
-- Asume VARBINARY(10) is the correct datatype
UPDATE dbo.table1
SET field = CONVERT(VARBINARY(10), 'F')
WHERE fieldID = 1;
GO
```